# Lost in Irssi and Znc

Tags: irssi

I'm using since a long time znc and irssi but sometimes i'm quite lost to identify my different network.

When I connect I do on **irssi**

- `/connect -ssl myserver.com +PORT nick:pass` for the first server
- `/connect -ssl myserver.com +PORT nick2:pass` for the second server
- etc

But the problem is when I switch between server in the status windows with **ctrl+x** all servers have the same name

- `[11:50]            --- | Server: Changed to  server myserver.com`
- `[11:50]            --- | Server: Changed to  server myserver.com`
- `[11:50]            --- | Server: Changed to  server myserver.com`

How can I fixed that?

I didn't see any `name` argument for `connect`

`CONNECT [-4 | -6] [-ssl] [-ssl_cert <cert>] [-ssl_pkey <pkey>] [-ssl_verify] [-ssl_cafile <cafile>] [-ssl_capath <capath>] [-noproxy] [-network <network>] [-host<hostname>] [-rawlog <file>] <address>|<chatnet> [<port> [<password> [<nick>]]]`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally register the network using `/SERVER ADD -auto -network NETWORKName irc.server.com +6667 nick:pass` but that the only way I've found.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the server, for example: 'Undernet':

```
/server 127.0.0.1 port username/undernet-znc:password` # 'undernet-znc' if your created a network with that name

/connect undernet
```

- reset your settings ufw & Iptables

activate in irssi disputch.pl, he sends commands to the server:

```
/run scriptassist

/script install dispatch.pl

/script load dispatch.pl

/script autorun dispatch.pl

Alt+2 Alt+3 Alt+4 Alt+5 Alt+6 # in irssi see error messages

/alias znc msg *status

/msg *status saveсonfig
```

but all the same, if you can’t succeed, restart the service and see what errors it gives:

```
sudo systemctl status znc.service

sudo systemd-analyze verify znc.service` # check for errors in the unit

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart znc.service

sudo systemctl status znc.service
```